# Why does utop flash?

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop

[image: flash on]

In utop (on osx), the black border around the yellow welcome message, and the red line between each command flash.

I thought it might be telling me to update something, but I can't find any message.

Is there a way to turn this off?  Or is it trying to tell me something?

[image: flash off]

Comment: This looks like a misconfigured terminal. You can try `printf '\e[36mtest\e[0m\n'` in the terminal (not in utop) - if the "test" text blinks it has nothing to do with `utop` itself.

Comment: @ÉtienneMillon - thanks.  That doesn't blink... solid cyan